# css: poner imagen de fondo y añadir dos imágenes mas en esquinas inferiores

Tags: css, imagen, div, class

Estoy trabajando con una hoja de estilos css y necesito a un párrafo añadirle una imagen de fondo rosa con un borde determinado y encima de esta imagen, en cada esquina inferior, añadir una imagen de una llama de fuego. Por el momento solo hemos aprendido    Lo intento hacer así pero no consigo que me aparezcan totalmente pegadas abajo.  Os muestro mis códigos, mi resultado y finalmente que es lo que quiero conseguir:

[image: mi código de la hoja de estilos css]Mi código de la hoja de estilos css.

[image: Mi código html]Mi código html.

[image: mi resultado obtenido fallido]Mi resultado obtenido fallido, llamas más altas de lo buscado.

[image: el resultado que espero encontrar: las llamitas pegadas abajo del todo, ya que esto ultimo no lo consigo, al estar un div contenido en otro div me quedan las llamitas mas altas]El resultado que espero encontrar: las llamitas pegadas abajo del todo, ya que esto ultimo no lo consigo, al estar un div contenido en otro div me quedan las llamitas mas altas.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Lo agradecería muchísimo, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código como texto y no como imagen? Puedes insertar código en la pregunta presionando Cntrl+M y te dejará insertar código que después se puede ejecutar.

Comment: Gracias, soy nueva en esto y no sabia como utilizarlo. Ya tengo resuelta la duda, lo conseguí, basándome  en la respuesta de enxaneta  que me dijo que usara background: url(...),url(..); mi problema persistía porque cada foto tenia un tamaño,  y la propiedad tamaño no la coge el background generico por llamardo de alguna forma sino que hay que poner background-size: tamañodelaimagen1, tamañodelaimagen2;  y asi ya lo solucioné. Si aun asi quereis que ponga el código ya corregido para que le sirva a alguien de ayuda, decidmelo y lo haré. Muchas gracias a ambos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¡¡Me alegro de que hayas obtenido la solución!! Te aconsejo que si te ha ayudado la respuesta de @enxaneta, la valores como positiva y pongas tu respuesta como una nueva respuesta. Tu respuesta la podrás aceptar después y así todos verán cómo solucionaste finalmente la pregunta. Un saludo y bienvenida ;)

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar varias imágenes de fondo para un solo elemento si separas los url de las varias imágenes con una coma.
Las imágenes aparecen apiladas, una encima de otra, de esta manera: la primera imagen ( el gato ) esta encima de la segunda ( el gato ), que esta encima de la tercera (la mariposa)

```css
*{margin:0;
padding:0;}
div{
height:100vh;
background:
url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat) bottom left,
url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat) bottom right,
url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/butterfly.jpg) center/cover; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Por favor lea más acerca de cómo [utilizar varias imágenes de fondo para un solo elemento](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/css3/background-multiple.php)